# Error Code: 1442. SQL Trigger / stored procedure / statement

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers, mysql-workbench

After I store my data in my db. I want to delete some rows. In order to do it I created a trigger before update that in turn calls a stored procedure. But I keep facing the same **error 1442**

My stored procedure

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `db`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `empty_procedure`()
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM articles where articleId IN ( SELECT * FROM (SELECT articleId FROM articles WHERE articleTitle = " " or articleHref = " " or ArticleImgSrc = " ") AS X);
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

My trigger :

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `db`.`articles_BEFORE_UPDATE`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `db`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `articles_BEFORE_UPDATE` BEFORE UPDATE ON `articles` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    call empty_procedure();
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I tested the stored procedure separately and it's working.

Comment: You've created a situation that is not allowed. During the trigger's action, there cannot be any other operations that read/write to the _same table_ that that invoked the trigger. Basically, while in the middle of the `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger, the stored procedure is attempting to do `DELETE`'s on the _same_ table. See the [3rd bullet item from the end of this list](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/8.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html#stored-routines-function-restrictions)

Comment: Yes ! after some research I figured that out. I've proceeded differently and it's working ! I'm facing a new problem : Error code 1288

Comment: That error, along with relative details, would likely need to be another question. Search this site for that error, there are some solutions.

Comment: *I want to delete some rows. In order to do it I created a trigger* If you want to delete something then use single DELETE statement. Trigger should solve another tasks.

Comment: @Ayoub When you report about error, provide **complete and unchanged** error message. It contains a lot of critical information - to provide the error number only is not enough.

Comment: @PaulT. it's exactly what i've done. I managed to fix all of my errors